# rotate display on nextbook Flex

Tags: display

Jumped through all of the hurdles to boot from thumb drive on this machine. Ran the "live" version instead of the install and am glad I did. I cannot find an option to "rotate display" for the display settings. This is a 2:1 computer that Walmart is selling hand over fist. It doesn't seem like any Linux distro has the "orientation" driver for lack of a better word. Your distro claimed good touch support, so I thought I would try it. I could get by with the lack of accurate touch support (mostly due to lack of orientation driver) but I *must* be able to rotate the screen.

Does anyone have a work around for this?